# ¿Necesita un usuario instalar mongodb para un programa en java que usa mongodb?

Tags: java, base-de-datos, mongodb

La cuestión es que estoy desarrollando un programa que usa mongodb a nivel local como base de datos.

Y lo que necesito saber es si la persona que vaya a usar mi programa necesitará instalar `mongodb` en su ordenador o si por el contrario la librería de mongodb que se aloja en mi programa se hace cargo de todo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por un lado está tu programa Java que se conecta a la base de datos `MongoDB` a través del driver de `MongoDB` para Java.
Por otro lado está el servidor `MongoDB`, con la base de datos y colecciones con la información.

Es necesario que los usuarios tengan acceso a ese servidor para que tu programa se pueda conectar a él. De lo contrario tendrían que instalarse un servidor `MongoDB` local, en sus máquinas, lo que no tendría sentido si la información debe ser compartida entre todos ellos.

Comment: Correcto. Entonces será mejor que use otra base de datos como sqlite o neodatis, pues es para uso local.

Comment: Como no me quedaba tranquilo y necesitaba verlo con mis ojos he desinstalado mongodb de mi ubuntu y he ejecutado el programa que hace uso de mongodb. No ha tenido problema para leer ni para escribir. Yo creo que al meter la librería en el programa, mongodb no necesita de ser instalado por el usuario.

Comment: ¿Seguro que has desinstalado el servidor local? No tiene sentido. En cualquier caso, sin exponer al exterior esos datos, otros usuarios no los verían.